# Create Dynamic tree with hide and unhide the child

Tags: php, jquery, css, mysql

I'm using a code in **php mysql** to create a **dynamic tree** base on mysql

This tree is dynamic can change every time base on mysql

**my question is**: How to add + - hide unhide in this tree view ??!!

when i click + on the parent the child appear and when i click on - the child disappear and the same thing if the child have a sub child and ..... for all

**This is the php code**

```
<?php
$parentID = !empty($_GET['parentID']) ? $_GET['parentID'] : 0;

if ($parentID) {
    $currentFolder=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `tbl_folders` WHERE `db_id` ='$parentID'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    while($currentFolderArray=mysqli_fetch_array($currentFolder)){
        $currentFolderName = $currentFolderArray['name'];
    }
}
$currentFolderName = empty($currentFolderName)? 'root': $currentFolderName;
function buildTreeHTML(&$list, $parentID = 0) {
    $isBranch = false;
    foreach ($list as $index => $element) {
        if($list[$index]['parent_id'] != $parentID) continue;
        if(!$isBranch) {
            echo '<ul class="main-ul">';
            $isBranch = true;
        }
       echo"<div class='edit'><a href='edit.php?id={$list[$index]['db_id']}'><img src='../img/edit.png'></a></div>";
        echo"<div class='delete'><a class='del'href='edit.php?delete={$list[$index]['db_id']}&parent_id={$list[$index]['parent_id']}' data-confirm='Are you sure to delete this item?'><img src='../img/delete.png'></a></div>";
echo "<li ><label><a href='dms.php?parentID={$list[$index]['db_id']}'>" . $list[$index]['name'] . '</a></label></li>';
        buildTreeHTML($list, $list[$index]['db_id']);
    }
    if ($isBranch) {
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
?>

<ul>
    <li><a href="dms.php">root</a></li>
    <?php
    $treeObject = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_folders`order by name asc")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $treeArray = [];
    while ($result = $treeObject->fetch_array()) {
    $treeArray[] = $result;
    }
    buildTreeHTML($treeArray);
    ?>
</ul>
```

**Html output from browser**

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="dms.php">root</a>
</li>
<ul class="main-ul">
<div class="edit">
<div class="delete">
<li>
<label>
<a href="dms.php?parentID=1">Accounting</a>
</label>
</li>
<div class="edit">
<div class="delete">
<li>
<label>
<a href="dms.php?parentID=7">GM</a>
</label>
</li>
<div class="edit">
<div class="delete">
<li>
<label>
<a href="dms.php?parentID=2">HR</a>
</label>
</li>
<div class="edit">
<div class="delete">
<li>
<label>
<a href="dms.php?parentID=3">IT</a>
</label>
</li>
<ul class="main-ul">
<div class="edit">
<div class="delete">
<li>
<label>
<a href="dms.php?parentID=4">Network</a>
</label>
</li>
</ul>
</ul>
</ul>
```

**image** 
[image]

Comment: Can you pls update question with output you of above `php` code? So we can test it to do so

Comment: @GopalJoshi please check above i put the output of html from the browser with an image how it's look and this output is dynamic base on mysql it will be changed

Comment: @GopalJoshi any help please!!?

Comment: Check here i have updated your html and js code https://jsfiddle.net/gopaljoshi73/k3bhyeqz/1/. please update php code for the same

Comment: @GopalJoshi i will test it and reply

Comment: @GopalJoshi i need to be + - because i have another idea when i click on the name of folder how can updated ?!

Comment: @GopalJoshi i have change it to an arrow icon but it's only work for the root i can't use it for the folder who have child how can i use it ??

Comment: can you share your code on jsfiddle pls

Comment: @GopalJoshi the php one ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128135/discussion-between-gopal-joshi-and-m7md).

Comment: @GopalJoshi Thank you it's work now :)

Comment: you are welcome:)